# ChatGPT with multilingual language

Tags: nlp, language-model

How it can answer with multilingual langauge ?

Maybe it's because it use GPT-3.5, since their dataset has Common Crawl dataset, which has more than 40+ languages.

And as I found that InstructGPT's paper shows that GPT-3 can handle this task as well, but it needs to use more careful prompts.

Maybe I should read the paper "PaLI: A Jointly-Scaled Multilingual Language-Image Model" that has similar work with multilingual language model's work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How it can answer with multilingual language?

The training set is multilingual, and if a text starts in some language, it'll most likely continue with the same language.

See {1} for an evaluation of ChatGPT in the multilingual setting.

---

References:

- {1} Lai, Viet Dac, Nghia Trung Ngo, Amir Pouran Ben Veyseh, Hieu Man, Franck Dernoncourt, Trung Bui, and Thien Huu Nguyen. "[ChatGPT Beyond English: Towards a Comprehensive Evaluation of Large Language Models in Multilingual Learning.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2304.05613.pdf)" arXiv preprint arXiv:2304.05613 (2023).